# Mechanical sphere eversion?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

One of the best math explainers of a complex topological concept is the animated illustration of the [eversion of a sphere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO61D9x6lNY) dedicated to Albert Marden, and I wondered if a mechanical analog/demonstrator was feasible. This took me down a rabbit hole, which eventually led to [a "phasing" tesseract](https://genuineideas.com/ArticlesIndex/phasing.html) mechanical prototype able to pass one plane through another.

So, is anyone aware of an alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

Sphere eversion based on Morin surface (there are different methods) can be modelled using paper folding or nylon strings. [Adam Bednorz's website](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/%7Eabednorz/eversion/index.html) explains how to do it.

Comment: Appreciate the reference. The origami approach is intuitive, the string method is more of a graphical illustration, as they really never "pass" through each other. Very helpful.